# Android: Releasing GPS

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

My Activity implements LocationListener as below

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {}
```

My LocationManager goes as below

```
mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

I can get the current GPS location using the method about.

Now I need to release the GPS when the Activity closes.

so my onPause method goes as below.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
    //System.exit(0);
    super.onPause();
}
```

But this doesn't release the GPS. Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be that there is another Location Listener that has called `requestLocationUpdates()`.

If not you should call `removeUpdates()` in `finish()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` just to make sure. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and let me know what happen.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
            mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
            mlocManager.removeGpsStatusListener(this);
    }
```

**Now I need to release the GPS when the Activity closes.**

Then put this code in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` of activity.